# open source msbuild tasks

Tags: msbuild, build-automation

I currently use http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ to help do additional stuff with MSBuild like get files from sourcesafe or compress javascript files.

Recently I have discovered a bug in one of the tasks I use that is a deal breaker.

Are there any other open source 3rd party tasks to extend msbuild?

Is http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ the most popular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [MSBuildContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildContrib)?

Answer (score 2):

Try ["msbuild extension pack"](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/). In my opinion this is the highest quality pack out there.
Dan

Answer (score 2):

[MSBuildExtensionPack](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildExtensionPack) over 280 MSBuild tasks.  Well documented, has almost everything you could need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at the following urls:

1. http://msbuildtasks.net/
2. http://www.codeplex.com/sdctasks